# Issues reading frames from an RTSP h.264 IP camera

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, h.264, rtsp, ip-camera

**The Problem:**
 I'm working on a reader for multiple ip camera streams. The application needs to run on a ubuntu AWS EC2 instance. I've been unsuccessful in trying to reliably fetch and decode the frames from RTSP h.264 streams.

**What I've Tried:** 
I've used OpenCV's and SciKit-Video's VideoCapture classes, neither of which could both fetch and decode the frames from my test stream. I have verified that my test stream is readable using VLC and openRTSP, so I believe this is an encoding issue.

I've also attempted to build some solutions using python's subprocess module to run the aforementioned command-line applications. This allows me to read the stream reliably, but it raises the issue that the decoder fails due to it (apparently) not finding the keyframe data it needs to decode the stream.

Below is the code for this example. It tells openRTSP to periodically save some amount of video as a separate file and uses an openCV VideoCapture to get a single frame from each of those samples. Code:

```
def openrtsp_thread(queue, feed_name, source, sample_time, intruder, cleanup=True):


     (major, minor, subminor) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

     cmd = 'openRTSP -V -4 -v -P ' + str(sample_time) + ' ' + source

     out_dir = '/aws_odw/frame-store/'+feed_name.replace(' ','-')+'/'

     try:
         os.mkdir(out_dir)
     except:
         print '[?]['+feed_name+']: Not creating new frame directory'
         pass

     os.chdir(out_dir)

     p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '))

     while True:
         try:

             for dirs, files, filenames in os.walk(out_dir):

                 for f in filenames:


                     cap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(out_dir, f))

                     if int(major) < 3:
                        fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
                     else:
                        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)



                 #for i in range(int(float(sample_time)*fps*0.5)):
                 ret, frame = cap.read()

                 cap.release()

                 print 'enqueueing...'
                 queue.put((feed_name, frame, intruder))


         except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
             print '[x]['+feed_name+']: keyboard interrupt, cleaning up...'
             break

     p.send_signal(signal.SIGUSR1)
     p.wait()
     print '[*]['+feed_name+']: exiting gracefully.'
```

Can anyone offer any pointers? I don't know much about video encoding, so I'm feeling pretty lost. Any help would be very appreciated.

Edit: the end goal here is to queue the frames in python for real-time precessing in a computer vision application.

Comment: Please elaborate what is the goal - to draw them, reencode them or ... ? It is hard to suggest a tool without knowing the goal. If you just need to save them ffmpeg command line invocation should be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to be able to periodically (a few times per second) queue frames for individual processing in Python (as numpy arrays). It would be best if the frames didn't have to be written to files, as the end-to-end latency of the application is a significant consideration.

Comment: ok, then I think using python bindings for ffmpeg is the way to go. I'll see if I can make up an example:)